# Is the apparent IP of a mobile device mostly-stable for a web session?

Tags: mobile, ip-address

Does the IP address that a web site sees for a mobile device (e.g., attached via GRPS, 3G, etc.) change frequently, or is it stable enough that it's unlikely to change for the duration of a normal user "session"?

I realize that the IP address is **not** specific to the device; it's going to be the IP address of the gateway through which the device is connected, which is shared across many (many) devices. (Just like devices connected via NAT, like users sharing a WiFi connection or people on a corporate network behind a firewall, all share the same public IP.) That's okay for my purposes. It's if it *changes* a lot for the same user, during a session (between sessions is okay), that would be problematic.

Basically, I'm linking user session cookies to the client IP we saw when the user authenticated, as an imperfect defense against [session hijack via cookie theft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cookie_theft_and_session_hijacking). It's imperfect; it's one of several measures used to reduce the attack surface. But it would cause trouble for mobile users if we constantly invalidated their sessions because their apparent IP address changed.

But the question isn't about session cookies, it's about the frequency with which the apparent IP address of the device changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't change in operators that I know (spain, Portugal, italy, southafrica) But there are 10-100 IPs for all consumers. Maybe you could use useragent and others operator/phone HTTP headers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, as I said, the IP address is *part* of the solution, not the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a few tests on your site, browse it from your phone and see when and if it changes  in the access_log. I doubt it will change often, but it might if you roam or if you are moving and changing towers.

Also if you want to prevent session hijack thrugh cookie theft, consider using a Https-Only cookie.

Comment: Well of course I can approach it empirically. But there are hundreds of devices and hundreds of networks. I'm looking for insight from people who've been there.

Comment: Well if you are going to use it accross hundreds devices and networks, you cant really know that your code will work for sure if you rely on ip-address for session. Id bet my wage youll run into carriers that change the ip-adress way too often for your code to work as expected.

Comment: Do you have any experience with this? Or are you speaking hypothetically?

Comment: Ive noticed my own phones IP-adress change when I travel within the same country.

Comment: `@AntonioP`: Okay, thanks. I'm not worried about it if someone's travelling. I'm talking sessions, 20-60 minutes. Of course, if you're on a train...but then, my experience of 3G on trains is that it tends not to be worth doing. :-)